# Failed to load edgegrid config when importing Akamai property into Pulumi

Tags: akamai, pulumi

I am trying out the new [import functionality](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/akamai/property/#import) for an Akamai property. When I run the import command inside a pulumi project, I get the error message below. What is this `.edgerc` file and how can I create it?

```
    Type                      Name                      Plan       Info
 +   pulumi:pulumi:Stack       vdp-akamai-akamai-import  create     1 error
 =   └─ akamai:index:Property  example                   import     1 error

Diagnostics:
  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (vdp-akamai-akamai-import):
    error: preview failed

  akamai:index:Property (example):
    error: Preview failed: 1 error occurred:
        * failed to load edgegrid config: unable to load config from environment or .edgerc file: loading config file: open /Users/vcui/.edgerc: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Akamai documentation, it looks like it's used as a config file that you can store your credentials in.

[Documentation found here](https://developer.akamai.com/api/getting-started#addcred)

Comment: Thanks, I followed those directions and set up an API client for myself.